# How do i do the checksum for Singapore Car License Plate Recognition with Python

Tags: python, ocr

I am able to do recognition of car license plate and extract the plate values. Sometimes, the results are inaccurate as i am using OCR to do the recognition. I uses a checksum to ensure only the correct results are being printed and viewed. After the calculation for the checksum, I need to use another formula to get the last letter of the plate. match with these 19 letter, A=0, Z=1, Y=2, X=3, U=4, T=5, S=6, R=7, P=8, M=9, L=10, K=11, J=12, H=13, G=14, E=15, D=16, C=17, B=18. Is there any way i can use a loop to like declare the values of this letters instead of doing it one by one manually? Please help out. Thank you.

Comment: A dictionary perhaps is what would make sense here.

Comment: If instead you need to get the letter *from* the value, then a list is even easier approach.

Comment: what code have you tried that's showing the error msg between SBA 1234G and SBA1234G. One with the space and one without the space. All you need to do is to check for space as you pass thru the list or dictionary for check and ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list and perform the lookups according to your needs.

The list looks like this:

```
plate_letter_list = ['A', 'Z', 'Y', 'X', 'U', 'T', 'S', 'R', 'P', 'M', 'L', 'K', 'J', 'H', 'G', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'B']
```

## Case 1: Lookup value from letter

If you need to find the numeric value associated with a letter, use the `index` method:

```
letter = 'T'
print(plate_letter_list.index(letter))
>> 5
```

## Case 2: Lookup letter from value

If you need to find the letter associated with a numeric value, use it as index:

```
value = 13
print(plate_letter_list[value])
>> H
```

Comment: is it possible to use ord function to do this?

Comment: Not in a trivial way: the letters are not in a fixed order. I think the dictionary is your best route.

Comment: I actually prefer now to use a list.

Comment: I have tested and it works well when the text is SBA 1234 but not SBA1234. Why does it only works when there is a space bar in between the SBA and 1234?

Comment: You would need to show us two things: (1) your code that implements this logic, (2) the spec of a valid license plate. Is the space allowed (or even meaningful)?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to search for these values. One of it is to use the **List** datatype like @sal provided. The other way is to use **Dictionary** datatype

**

### Solution using List Datatype

**

`pl_vals_list = ['A', 'Z', 'Y', 'X', 'U', 'T', 'S', 'R', 'P', 'M', 'L', 'K', 'J', 'H', 'G', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'B']`

You can then do a lookup either by **position** or by **value**

To search by **position**, will provide you the value you assigned to the alphabet.

`print(pl_vals_list[0])`. This will result in `A`.

Alternatively, you can search by the alphabet itself. In this case, you have to use the `index()` function.

`print(pl_vals_list.index('A'))`. This will result in the assigned number you gave to the alphabet. The result will be `0`

This provides you a means to look-up based on alphabet or value.

You can also check if the alphabet is inside the list using:

```
if 'A' in pl_vals_list:
    #then do something for value A
elif 'B' in pl_vals_list:
    #then do something for value B
else:
    #then do something
```

You can also iterate through the list using a for loop and enumerate. However, I don't know if that will be of value to you.

```
for i, v in enumerate(pl_vals_list):
    #do something with each value in the list
    #here i will store the index, and v will have the value - A, B, C, etc
```

You can get the value of each of these and determine what you want to do.

**

### Solution using Dictionary Datatype

**

Similarly, you can do the same using a dictionary.

`pl_vals_dict = {'A':0, 'Z':1, 'Y':2, 'X':3, 'U':4, 'T':5, 'S':6, 'R':7, 'P':8, 'M':9, 'L':10, 'K':11, 'J':12, 'H':13, 'G':14, 'E':15, 'D':16, 'C':17, 'B':18}`

To look for alphabets within a dictionary, you can use

```
if 'A' in pl_vals_dict.keys():
    #then do something for value A
elif 'A' in pl_vals_dict.keys():
    #then do something for value B
else:
    #do something else
```

An alternate way to check for something would be:

```
x = True if 'F' in pl_vals_dict.keys() else False
```

In this case `x` will have a value of `False`

You can also use the get() function to get the value.

```
x = pl_vals_dict.get('A')  # OR

print (pl_vals_dict.get('A')
```

The simplest way to look up a dictionary value is:

```
print (pl_vals_dict['A'])
```

which will result in `0`

However, you have to be careful if you try to print value of 'F', it will throw an error as 'F' is not part of the key value pair within the dictionary.

```
print (pl_vals_dict['F'])
```

this will give you the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#48>", line 1, in <module>
    pl_vals_dict['F']
KeyError: 'F'
```

Similar to list, you can also iterate through the dictionary for keys and values. Not sure if you will need to use this but here's an example for you.

```
for k, v in pl_vals_dict.items():
    #do something with each pair of key and value
    #here k will have the keys A Z Y X ....
    #and v will have the values 1, 2, 3, 4, ....
```

Comment: I have managed to do this part, Now i facing an issue where like when i recognise the plate, it sometimes show SBA1234G and sometimes show SBA 1234G where there is a space bar in between SBA and 1234G. which cause the code to not work.